# Installing netcdf4-python with parallel IO support

Tags: python, ubuntu, parallel-processing, netcdf4

I want to install netcdf4-python with parallel IO support on Ubuntu 18.04. So far, I have worked with the pip-package but I guess for parallel IO support I will have to compile the source code myself. However, I'm a bit lost in the descriptions and the dependencies and would be very happy about any help.

The [Instructions](https://unidata.github.io/netcdf4-python/netCDF4/index.html) say that an MPI-enabled versions of the netcdf library is required and I also need a MPI-enabled HDF5 or the PnetCDF library. Do I need to build them myself with the respective options or are there any library packages available in Ubuntu? I have installed `libpnetcdf-dev` but it looks like `nc-config` (which is used by netcdf4-python by default to find the location of the dependencies) cannot find that. It reports `--has-pnetcdf-> no`. So how can I get parallel IO to work?

Comment: What I read from the instructions, the netCDF4 library will decide the MPI possibility based on the availability of parallel HDF5 or PNetCDF. Basically, either you build HDF5 with MPI support (I guess it is written in instructions of buidling HDF5 how to set it up with MPI support) or you additionally install PnetCDF (http://cucis.ece.northwestern.edu/projects/PNETCDF/index.html) and set it up so that Python/system knows the existence of the library. I think the "--has-pnetcdf" means that the HDF5 has parallel support as netCDF library is built on top of that.